# Is document.getElementById('id') or $('#id') still necessary to select an element by ID?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I came across this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2992949) today, and in the comments the author mentioned that

```
var log = document.getElementById('log');
```

is unnecessary, because in Javascript you can just use `log` to access the DOM element. Is this true across all browsers? Is there a name/reference for this technique?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2992949#gistcomment-398992

Comment: He didn't explicitly say yes or no; I am interested to know if this works across most/all modern browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly this is actually in the HTML5 spec, so 
yes it will work and no it is not a legacy feature as it is being suggested (anymore at least - it used to be an IE only trick).

You can read the spec here,
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object

I will agree that it's actually clutters the namespace, and would take the liberty to suggest against using it - but it will and does work on every major browser!

Comment: You are right! The relevant W3C spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 4):

Under Internet Explorer where IDs will become global variables and accessible everywhere by that name.

I regard this 'misfeature' as a bad thing.

I don't recall all of the features and aspects of it and I do my best to try and pretend it never happened.

In short: IE-only "feature" -- best ignored. Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/10/22/internet-explorer-creates-global-variables-for-each-object-in-the-dom.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @Jim: Chrome implemented some of IE's features, also the global `event` object. It still does not make it a good feature.

Comment: There are more details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/10/22/internet-explorer-creates-global-variables-for-each-object-in-the-dom.aspx

Comment: @JimLim -- Didn't realize that Chrome copied it.  I still stand by my recommendation of **ignore it**.

Comment: I totally agree. It pollutes the namespace unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dubious "feature" that shouldn't be used for anything. It introduces global state and globally scoped variables which are one of the main points to avoid in any application and more importantly seems only to work in Internet Explorer and some versions of Chrome. It is almost certain to be less performant, since not only does the browser have to access the DOM but it also must look for a variable named `log` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For new versions of modern browsers it might work, but older version will not handle it fine. If you want your site works in older browser, do it using document.getElementById.

Comment: This isn't a feature of modern browsers; rather, it's a (dubious) feature from *legacy* browsers.

Comment: It might work, but that's not the point.  It's a legacy feature, and one that's not standardized.

Comment: I think the most salient point is that it works on some browsers, but not others. So if you want as much compatibility as possible, don't do it.